# How do I get information for new element in column from other rows in dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, diff

For a project I want to get the total time the was used to scrabble. 
I have a data frame in which there is a LocalTime column. Now I want to add a column to this dataframe with the difference between the localTime now, and the localTime from the previous element. 
When using the diff function, I get the following message:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "TimeSpend", value = c(1.5577, 1.0657,  : 
  replacement has 49313 rows, data has 49314
```

How can I fix this?

At the moment I have simply  used this:

```
dualTaskTime$TimeSpend <- NA
dualTaskTime$TimeSpend <- diff(dualTaskTime$LocalTime)
```

Comment: `diff` returns one element less. So you could do something like `dualTaskTime$TimeSpend <- c(NA, diff(dualTaskTime$LocalTime))`

Comment: yes, thank you! I didn't know yet that you could also insert different values in a column like this in one step:)